# Export Private ed25519 Key From GnuPG For Use in SSH

Tags: ssh, gpg

Is there a way to create an id_ed25519 (not id_ed25519.pub) file from an ed25519 keypair stored in GnuPG?

I've started keeping track of my SSH keys in GPG:

```
sec   rsa3072 2017-12-12 [C]
      DDD8CEFDE281D48CBBF0C56FE2AA8C94C8A7C456
uid           [ultimate] Dave <dave@example.com>
ssb   rsa3072 2017-12-12 [S]
ssb   rsa3072 2017-12-12 [E]
ssb   rsa3072 2017-12-12 [A]
ssb   ed25519 2017-12-12 [A]
```

To export my public keys for use by SSH, I'm using the `--export-ssh-key` option in GnuPG that's been available since 2.1. This works for both the RSA and the ed25519 keys.

```
$ gpg -o id_rsa.pub --export-ssh-key 5D61D0F9!
$ gpg -o id_ed25519.pub --export-ssh-key 0A072B72!
```

(The ! forces GnuPG to use the specified subkey and not the first available authentication key.)

To export the private RSA key I've used a workflow like this:

```
$ gpg --export-secret-subkeys \
--export-options export-reset-subkey-passwd 0A072B72! | \
openpgp2ssh 0A072B72 > id_rsa
```

This creates an RSA private key that SSH can understand, but with no passphrase.

To re-add a passphrase I use:

```
$ ssh-keygen -p -f id_rsa
```

On my Windows workstation I convert the key to something PuTTY can understand with PuTTYGen.

This falls apart with ed25519 keys because `openpgp2ssh` doesn't handle ed25519 keys.

From what I can tell, some people are using their GPG keyrings with SSH directly, but that won't work for me. I need the private key separated out to use with PuTTY on Windows.